# How can I setup shortcuts in Eclipse to format elements in Javadoc?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, javadoc

When writing Javadocs in Eclipse, one usually need to format some things like `<i>someArgumentName</i>` or `<code>hereIs.aPiece(); // of code</code>`.

How can I configure shortcuts to add tags like `<code>`, `<pre>`, `<b>` and `<i>` for writing Javadocs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you begin writing something like `<code` in the javadoc and press Ctrl + Space, auto completion should kick in and give you `<code></code>`.

I created a quick screen cast to show what I mean. Take a look at it [**here**](http://youtu.be/hU7LWVok6TE).

You can take a look at the default configured code templates like these in Eclipse Preferences by going to `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates` like so :

[image]

Notice the use of `${word_selection}` in the template Preview above.

Comment: I didn't know it worked for a selection! that was great, thanks!